# Issues with Dell Latitude E5570 - Not Caching Domain Credentials

Tags: windows, group-policy, credentials

When our users are off the network, they are unable to login to their laptops.   They receive the "no logon servers" error.  I have verified the "Interactive Logon: Domain controller (paraphrased)" GPO is not "defined", and we are allowing Windows to cache credentials.

Doesn't seem to make a difference.   When the DC is not available, they cannot login.  I need my users to be able to use their laptops at home without a DC present.

This is not an issue with the HP laptops we have on our network.  However, there is a walled garden for HP encryption prior to the Windows logon screen.

EDIT: During setup of the laptops, before we even deploy them, we log in to their account on the network to ensure the profiles has been created on the local computer

Suggestions for the Dell laptops? Windows 7 Pro BTW.

Comment: have they ever logged into them on the network before they take them home?  if not, this is a fundamental requirement of 'cached' creds...

Comment: During setup of the laptops, before we even deploy them, we log in to their account on the network to ensure the profiles has been created on the local computer. (added to original question.  Apologies for not noting that.)

Comment: Does it work to login from home but with the wifi/lan connection at off?

Comment: nope.  Thats what we are trying to enable.